# node with name "rabbit" already running after changing the Erlang cookie

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I'm trying to create a two node rabbitmq cluster. I've setup the rabbitmq server successfully on both nodes. After replacing the slave's node cookie with the master's `.erlang.cookie`. System is unable to start rabbitmq app.

I'm executing the following commands:

- nohup rabbitmq-server restart &
- rabbitmqctl start_app
- /sbin/service rabbitmq-server stop

nohup is generating the following logs in `/var/lib/rabbitmq/nohup.log`

```
ERROR: node with name "rabbit" already running on "ip-172-31-83-71"
ERROR: node with name "rabbit" already running on "ip-172-31-83-71"
ERROR: node with name "rabbit" already running on "ip-172-31-83-71"
```

Also terminal is following the following error:

```
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@ip-172-31-83-71'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@ip-172-31-83-71']

rabbit@ip-172-31-83-71:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on ip-172-31-83-71
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  no other nodes on ip-172-31-83-71
  * suggestion: start the node

Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-26458-rabbit@ip-172-31-83-71'
 * effective user's home directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq
 * Erlang cookie hash: aoPchC2KIy7esHVGVNLP4w==
```

I've also tried by revert the `.erlang.cookie` and in this case it's working fine. Can anyone please guide me what I'm missing?

Comment: Did you change the Erlang cookie while the `rabbitmq` server was running?

Comment: I first stopped the server and then made the change

Comment: Try killing the rabbitmq process. You can get it process ID by running `ps -ax | grep rabbit`. Then change your `.erlang.cookie` and start the server